# Submit form with an array input - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an a column called `access` and it's set to `array: true`. I'm having trouble submitting a form with this however. Here is my controller:

#### Controller

```
def create
   @topic = Topic.find_by(slug: params[:topic_id])
   @navigation_item = NavigationItem.create(navigation_item_params)

   if @navigation_item.persisted?
      redirect_to topic_path(params[:topic_id])
   else
     render :new
   end
end

private

def navigation_item_params
  params.require(:navigation_item).permit(
    :title,
    :url,
    :thumbnail_id,
    :access,
    :category_id,
    :tag
  )
end
```

Pretty standard stuff in the controller

#### Form

```
<%= form.select :access, options_for_select(custodian_profiles), { include_blank: true, multiple: true }, class: "form-control #{error_class}" %>
```

I also have a presence true validation on the field.

So, when I try to submit the form the `access` field comes back as an empty array it looks like this `#=> access: []` which obviously fails the validation check and doesn't work. How do I accept multiple select values with rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you may need another pair of brackets, try this:

```
<%= f.select :access, options_for_select(custodian_profiles), {}, {:multiple => true, :class => "form-control #{error_class}", include_blank: true } %>
```

Also make sure that your `custodian_profiles` variable is returning an array.  Hope that helps.